# Locking PC in Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pygtk

i'm doing application that locks the PC using pyGtk, but i have a problem, when i click on the ok button the function of the button should get the time from the textbox, hide the window then sleep for a while, and at last lock the pc using a bash command. but it just don't hide.

and here is the [complete program](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/616034/ParentalControl.py)

Comment: We need more information, please post all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

Provided you are using Gnome on Ubuntu

```
import os

os.system('gnome-screensaver-command –-lock')
```

Comment: His problem is that his window isn't hiding.

Comment: i already use this command to lock my screen but i need to hide the window

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason for the main class to be a thread? I would make it just a normal class, which would be a lot easier to debug. The reason its not working is that all gtk related stuff must happen in the gtk thread, so do all widget method calls like this: `gobject.idle_add(widget.method_name)`. So to hide the password window: `gobject.idle_add(self.pwdWindow.hide)`

You'll have to `import gobject` first of course (You might need to install it first).

**EDIT:** I don't think that that was your problem, either way I edited your program a lot, here is the modified [code](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/961121/ParentalControl.py.tar.gz).

Comment: I just noticed that you updated the link to your code see my edited answer.